# call directly to a rails application with Twilio

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, twilio

I'm working with rails 4. I know about Twilio click to call, however, I want someone out there on the phone network to be able to call my Twilio registered number directly, (providing it is a number known to my rails app). I currently have a trial Trilio account. At present, I get an automated message saying the number is not connected. Will this go away when I upgrade to a full account?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When someone calls your Twilio phone number, [Twilio will make an HTTP request](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request) with all the details about the call to a URL that you provide for the number. To tell Twilio what to do with that call you need to return [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml) which is an XML formatted list of instructions for what to do with the call. You can achieve this with a Rails application by returning TwiML from an action and using a URL that points at that action on the server.

That's the short description. I recommend you read through this blog post on [integrating Twilio with a Rails 4 app](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/02/twilio-on-rails-integrating-twilio-with-your-rails-4-app.html) that was written by my colleague Carter. I also wrote a post on [making phone calls to a Rails 5 application](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/05/calling-rails-5-getting-started-with-twilio-on-rails.html) which is mostly applicable to Rails 4 if you want a slightly different perspective.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: What I wanted to know is, "can I make a voice call directly to my rails app through twilio". It turns out you can. The reason it's not working for me is because I have a trial account. Twilio click to call, however, does work with a trial account if you set the "Primary Handler Fails" for your messaging webhook URL to point to your voice URL.

Comment: You should be able to do that with a trial account, especially if the fallback URL works! Are there errors in the [Twilio debugger](https://www.twilio.com/console/dev-tools/debugger) that can help you here?

Comment: Hi Phil. The problem I have is I get a message saying, "The number is not connected". This is a well known message in Australia. It comes from our phone system, not Twilio. I guess, "click to call" works because even though the call is instigated externally through a web browser, the call itself is instigated by my rails app. It is an outgoing call from my rails application. I believe, when I change to a paid account, Twilio will register the number in Australia and it will all work. Please let me know if I'm on the wrong track.

Comment: This sounds like it might be best taken off SO, can you drop me an email at philnash@twilio.com and explain what steps you've gone through to get to the point that you get "The number is not connected". Thanks!